# Regex replace for String, 3 characters from the end

Tags: regex, string, replace

I have been able to add a space to a string in an input field using the following:

```
onkeypress="this.value=this.value.replace(/^(\w{5})(?=\w)/,'$1 ')"
```

But I would like the count to start from the end of the line, and add a space after user input has stopped. I've also tried onblur, but this does not seem to work in chrome.

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use inline event handlers, ESPECIALLY not if it's more than just a plain function call!

Comment: What is this - javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess  -

```
onkeypress="this.value=this.value.replace(/(\w{5})(?=\w$)/,'$1 ')"
```